# UIScrollView won't stay in place after user finishes scrolling

Tags: ios

Within my UIView, I have a UIScrollView which fills the first view, so than when the content is bigger than the iPhone screen size, the user can scroll the page down. It works well, but when the user finishes the scroll movement - i.e. removes his fingers, the page snaps back into it's original position. Obviously that is not what I want, how can it be avoided?

Here is the relevant code in the UIView class which declares and uses the UIScrollView class.

```
@implementation TestView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }

    CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    scrollView.canCancelContentTouches=NO;
    [self addSubview:scrollView];

    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];

    CGRect rectForBigRedSquare = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);
    UILabel *redSquare = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectForBigRedSquare];
    [redSquare setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [scrollView addSubview:redSquare];
    return self;
}
```

An additional question is this: how is it possible to make it such that the user can only scroll down, that is to see content at the bottom which was out of view, but not to scroll up so that there is space before the start of the content. In

Comment: I've had this problem also, haven't found a satisfactory answer. Think its more a bug than anything else.

Comment: I could answer your additional question, but you should ask it as a separate question. Asking it like this does not help any future visitors with that problem.

Comment: One more thing, you should place your initialization code where it says "//initialization code.". ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just have to set contentSize of your scrollview according to the contents.

```
CGSize scrollViewSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);
[self.myScrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the easiest way to get this scrollview working as you desire is to ensure that content size of the scrollview ***is identical to the frame size of the content*** you wish to scroll.

You can achieve this by having a content view into which you add all the views you wish to be visible and then add that content view to the scrollview while ensuring that the content size of the scrollview is set to the content view's frame size.

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

    UIView* contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 460)];

    UIView* redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [redView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [contentView addSubview:redView];
    [redView release];

    UIView* blueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(960, 0, 320, 460)];
    [redView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [contentView addSubview:blueView];
    [blueView release];

    CGSize contentViewSize = contentView.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:contentView];
    [scrollView setContentSize:contentViewSize];
    [contentView release];

    [self addSubview:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

The app I was working on had similar symptoms.  The user could scroll down but on release the view would snap back to the initial position. The page was set up as follow:

`[VIEW]
   [SAFE AREA]
   [SCROLL VIEW]
       [CONTENT VIEW]`

I strongly suspect that a combination of Auto-Layout and manual constraints caused by several adjustment iterations was causing the issue. To resolve this all constraints where removed from the View.

The Scroll View was assigned the following constraints:

```
Scroll View.leading = Safe Area.leading
Scroll View.top     = Safe Area.top
Scroll View.trailing= Safe Area.trailing
Scroll View.bottom  = Safe Area.bottom
```

The Content View was then assign the following constraints

```
ContentView.Leading = Scroll View.Leading
ContentView.top     = Scroll View.top
ContentView.centerX = ScrollView.centerX
```

The Content View was also given the following self constraint

```
height = 1000
```